# Rails: order the results returned from DISTINCT ON * ORDER

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following Rails models: `Chat` and `Messages` where a chat can have many messages. I have the following Rails query to pull the last message from the user for each chat where he is a recipient:

```
def index
  messages = Message.where(recipient_id: id)
                    .select('DISTINCT ON ("chat_id") *')
                    .order(:chat_id, created_at)
end
```

This gives me the last message to the user of each chat that the user is a part of. I would now like to sort the results of this query by when the messages were created so that the latest messages go to the top. However, if I add

`sorted = messages.order(created_at: :desc)`

It doesn't sort the results of the first query, it simply appends the order by to the first query (which I know is the expected behavior) so I don't get a sorted list by created date. How can I do an order by to the result of the first query? Essentially something that would mimic the following with Rails syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (chat_id) *
      FROM messages
      ORDER BY chat_id, created_at DESC) last_messages
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
Message.from(
  Message.where(recipient_id: id)
    .select('DISTINCT ON ("chat_id") *')
    .order("chat_id, created_at DESC"), 
    :messages
).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: This is great. I wasn't aware of the `from` query option. Very elegant and just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The first option is to [unscope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/unscope) the `:order` of `messages` then order it again with your desired column.

```
sorted = messages.unscope(:order).order(created_at: :desc)
```

In case you can't unscope the `messages`, another option is turning `messages` into a subquery.

```
sorted = Message.where(id: messages).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: I prefer the second option since (to me) its more semantic but I had to add `pluck(:id)` to make it work: `sorted = Message.where(id: messages.pluck(:id)).order(created_at: :desc)`. I upvoted your answer but @PGill had the most elegant solution solution so I gave him the check.

Comment: Thanks, totally agree that PGill's answer is better

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this -

```
def index
  messages = Message.where(recipient_id: id)
                .select('DISTINCT ON ("chat_id") *, created_at')
                .order(:chat_id, created_at)
                .sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
end
```

Comment: This is good but this requires a sql query and then Ruby to process the results, whereas the other two answers just require a sql query.

Comment: I agree and appreciate your feedback